# I would like to get the php array from the javascript array with changed keys

Tags: javascript

I have generated an array from an excel file and gotten this result.

Current result : This is the result I got from reading from the excel file

```
[
  {name: "mike floss", occupation: "student", age: 19, nickname: "mike", __rowNum__: 1},
  {name: "john blake", occupation: "student", age: 20, nickname: "john", __rowNum__: 2},
  {name: "dan brown", occupation: "police officer", age: 25, nickname: "dan", __rowNum__: 3}
]
```

Expected result: This is what I would like to get, I used json_encode() to display this.

```
{
  dan: {name: "dan brown", occupation: "police officer", age: 25},
  john: {name: "john blake", occupation: "student", age: 20},
  mike: {name: "mike floss", occupation: "student", age: 19}
}
```

This is what I have tried

```
function changekeys(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const mapped = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {

            if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(item[i]['nickname'])) {
                acc[item[i]['nickname']] = [];
            }

            acc[item[i]['nickname']].push(item);

            return acc;

        }, {});

        console.log(mapped);
    }
}
```

and I have called the function in another function.

```
changekeys(newArr);
```

I kept getting the error, 'nickname' is not defined.

Comment: So, you just want to change the numerical keys to be the nickname?

Comment: Why loop and reduce. Looks like the reduce is the only thing you need

Comment: yes and I would like to make it a php array if it's possible as well.

Comment: I used the loop so that i can get the indexes 0,1 and 2

Comment: Your browser has no concept of what PHP is. It's a [Server Side Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side). By the time it comes to rendering your Javascript, PHP has been and gone.If you want this information in PHP, then read the excel file using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume since you have arrays in the accumulator that you meant to do this?

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "mike floss", "occ": "student", "nickname": "mike" }, 
  { "name": "john blake", "occ": "student", "nickname": "john" }, 
  { "name": "john something else", "occ": "bla", "nickname": "john" }, 
  { "name": "dan brown", "occ": "policeman", "nickname": "dan" }
]
const mapped = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const nick = item.nickname;
  if (!acc[nick]) acc[nick] = [item];
  else acc[nick].push(item);

  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(mapped);
```

If you just want to use the nickname as key, then nickname has to be unique and then this is all you need

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "mike floss", "occ": "student", "nickname": "mike" }, 
  { "name": "john blake", "occ": "student", "nickname": "john" }, 
  { "name": "dan brown", "occ": "policeman", "nickname": "dan" }
]
let mapped = {}
arr.forEach(item => {
  mapped[item.nickname] = item;
  delete mapped[item.nickname].nickname
})  

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achievable using a `reduce` function

```js
function changekeys(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((result, person) => {
       result[person.nickname] = {
           name: person.name,
           occupation: person.occupation,
           age: person.age
       }
       return result;
    }, {})
}

const data = [
  {name: "mike floss", occupation: "student", age: 19, nickname: "mike", __rowNum__: 1},
  {name: "john blake", occupation: "student", age: 20, nickname: "john", __rowNum__: 1},
  {name: "dan brown", occupation: "police officer", age: 25, nickname: "dan", __rowNum__: 1}
]

console.log(changekeys(data))
```

Comment: That is not very elegant. See my second example